# Are function parameters just variables? Should I reassign them?

Tags: javascript, variables, arguments

In Javascript, are function parameters just like variables? I can reassign them inside the function body just like any variable (seems to work well), is that "good practice" or should I store the parameter in a variable instead and then reassign the variable?

```
function example(a) {
    a = 5;
    return a;
}

function example2(a) {
    var b = a;
    b = 5;
    return b;
}
```

Is there *any* difference here?

Comment: What do you mean by function arguments? Are you talking about the arguments object or parameters you pass into a function? What do you mean by `reassign IT ... just like variables`? Can you elaborate with an example please to showcase the exact scenario you are referring to? As the question stands it is very much open to interpretation and any answer may or may not answer your question or might not even be close to addressing what you are referring to.

Comment: Unless it's a code golf competition, assign your function to a variable. Function declarations feel like a promise that a certain block of code is going to be accessible by some name. Variables, on the other hand -- well, I expect them to vary.

Comment: Refer to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: so basically YES (they are declared) and NO (assigning to other variables for using it is a not necessary overhead).

Comment: I updated the question. I used the word argument when I mean parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the assignment of an argument to a new variable is the only use of it, then you generate an overhead by creating a new variable and by confusing readers of the code, because they expect some other use of the argument.

If you never use the argument again, then stay with the argument and use it, even for new assignments.

```
function example2(a) {
    var b = a; // now a is never used again
    b = 5;
    return b;
}
```